# Fastest way to remove/hide a lot of elements from a list

Tags: javascript

I have a dropdown that contains around 100,000 rows which make up a list.

```
<input id="search" type="text" />
<ul>
    <li>item 1</li>
    <li>item 2</li>
        ...
    <li>item 100,000</li>
</ul>
```

I have a text box which acts as a search, so as you type it matches the input to items in the list, removing what does not match. This is the class I wrote to perform the removing of list elements.

[See the fiddle (list has about 2000 items)](http://jsfiddle.net/bWtpy/10/)

```
// requires jQuery
var Search = (function(){

    var cls = function (name) {
        var self = this;

        self.elem = $('#' + name);
        self.list = $('#' + name).next('ul').children();
        self.elem.bind('keyup', function () { self.change(); }); 
    };

    cls.prototype = {
        change: function () {
            var self = this;
            // gets the closest ul list
            var typed = self.elem.val();

            // only do something if there is something typed
            if (typed !== '') {
                // remove irrelevent items from the list
                self.list.each(function () {
                    var item = $(this).html();
                    if (item.indexOf(typed) === -1)  {
                        $(this).addClass('zero');
                        // tried using a class with visibility hidden
                    } else {
                        $(this).removeClass('zero');
                    }
                });
            } else {
                // check what list items are 'hidden' and unhide them
                self.list.each(function () {
                    if ($(this).hasClass('zero')) {
                        $(this).removeClass('zero');
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    };
    return cls;
}());
```

I am just adding a class which adds a height of 0, and no margin,padding, etc, but I have also tried using visibility:hidden. I have also tried using the detach method in jQuery but this is about the same in terms of speed.

Are their any JavaScript experts who can see any problems with the code, or offer some optimization techniques?

Comment: What is the result you are expecting? Its seems working to me.

Comment: If you are looking for optimization, posting on http://codereview.stackexchange.com would be a better choice.

Comment: I want to make it faster. With more than 40k rows it takes about 20 seconds in between key presses

Comment: How about rebuilding the list by sending AJAX request to the server?

Comment: @Starx Server side is probobly the best way - anything on the client is just too sluggish

Comment: There is a lot of redundant code  that could be cleared up to make this run faster.

Comment: @alex, But still clearing those may not be give the performance desired.

Comment: @ErrolGongson, More on it the list can be cached somewhere like in XML, eliminating the need to query the database.

Comment: @Starx Maybe not, but worth trying if the OP really wants to keep them all on the client.

Comment: Every `$(this)` has a huge overhead, cache it at the start of each function. Better yet use `while` loops instead of `.each` to avoid extra functions as they too have quite a bit of overhead.

Comment: @PaulS. thanks, I will definitely factor out $(this)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be done "relatively well" (in a desktop browser anyway), even with a large number of items - although the actual performance will vary based upon other factors.

The "trick" to keeping the UI responsive is to handle the searching/filtering over time via `setTimeout` or `setInterval` that only "do so much work at a time". I found that, at least in IE7/8 a work/rest of 20ms/30ms worked well for when I used such in a Sidebar Gadget. YMMV.

If the DOM can be *avoided for searching* entirely (e.g. using a cache to re-create the n-items on-the-fly from an array or other searchable structure), then this might payout as well - run some benchmarks! - and keep the searching simpler.

Of course, utilizing server-side solutions (e.g. AJAX), at least for "coarse grained results", may also be more appropriate depending upon use-case ..

Comment: Thanks for your insight. I will play around with a timeout and see if it helps me in this case.

Comment: @ErrolGongson - the second idea in this answer is the best one. Use an object/array cache of items that contains the actual data and then search through that, rather than the DOM. Then build the HTML from the matching object/array entries and add it to the DOM.

Comment: I am getting much much better performance using an array as a cache. Searching the dom seems to be the bottleneck indeed. Thanks a lot for suggesting this.

Comment: @ErrolGongson Cool, glad you found a solution :)

Answer (score 3):

Keeping 40k rows in is not a realistic solution when people will always use only small subset. What you can do is to cache it.

1. keep only those that were used most.
2. The more its used the more it'll appear at top.
3. If its never used it'll never appear. Launch an ajax request for such case.